# is there any npm package for counting the number of words of a doc/docx file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to count the number of words in doc/docx files on a server using express.js. Is there any suitable package for me?

Answer (score 3):

You might consider a combination of these two packages:

First extract:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/textract

Then count:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/count-words